# Latex randomly skips a line (or not)

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, line-spacing

Consider the following example:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \RequirePackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \RequirePackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
 \mdfdefinestyle{proof}{
   skipabove         = 1\baselineskip ,
   skipbelow         = 0\baselineskip ,
   leftmargin        = 0pt ,
   rightmargin       = 0pt ,
   innermargin       = 0pt ,
   innertopmargin    = .4em ,
   innerleftmargin   = .3em ,
   innerrightmargin  = 0pt ,
   innerbottommargin = .23em ,
   hidealllines      = true ,
   singleextra       = {
     \draw (O) -- ++(0,.450em) (O) -- ++(.450em,0) ;
     \draw (P-|O) -- ++(0,-.450em) (P-|O) -- ++(.450em,0) ;
   },
   firstextra        = {
     \draw (P-|O) -- ++(0,-.450em) (P-|O) -- ++(.450em,0) ;
   },
   secondextra       = {
     \draw (O) -- ++(0,.450em) (O) -- ++(.450em,0) ;
   },
 }
 \surroundwithmdframed[style=proof]{proof}
 \newcommand{\Title}[1]{\leftskip=0.0cm{\textbf{\\#1:}}}
 \begin{document}
   \Title{Test 1}
   \lipsum[1-3]
   \begin{proof}\hangindent0.5cm
   %\lipsum[4]  %Makes it one page
   \lipsum[4-5] %Makes the proof go to the 2nd page
   \end{proof}
   \Title{Test 2}
 \end{document}
```

The problem is: When a proof is only on one page, there is exactly one line between the next proof and the next title. But if the proof goes over one page, this extra line disappears (see image below). Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

[image]

Comment: I wonder why the first answer was deleted. The posted solution works perfectly fine. :/

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Sorry for asking, but how is github related to my question? I am not looking for a collaborating tool.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Do you have something to add here?

Comment: @JosephWright: I think we can close this question because it is fixed with the current version at github. What do you think?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel If the problem is fixed in the release version we have been closing, provided the release was (or at least appeared to be made) before the question, on the grounds 'first make sure your system is up to date' is reasonable. Otherwise, I guess an answer saying it will be fixed is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The output of a non-split frame and a split frame had different definitions. The current version at github fixes this issue.

However I recommend using a definition suggested by Gonzalo Medina:

```
\newcommand{\Title}[1]{\par\vskip\baselineskip\noindent\textbf{#1:}}
```